# How to cast an 'int' to a 'char' in C#?

Tags: c#, casting, char, int

I have a string variable which has a mixture of numbers and letters. I want to create a new string that only has `int` values of the previous string variable. So I found two ways to cast `int` to `char`. However, they do not work. Here's what I've tried

```
string onlyNumberString = "";
foreach (char onlyNum in puzzleData)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (onlyNum == (char)i)
        {
            onlyNumberString += onlyNum;
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
string onlyNumberString = "";
foreach (char onlyNum in puzzleData)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (onlyNum == Convert.ToChar(i))
        {
            onlyNumberString += onlyNum;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Char.IsDigit instead, far simpler.

```
StringBuilder onlyNumber = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char onlyNum in puzzleData)
{
    if (Char.IsDigit(onlyNum))
    {
        onlyNumber.Append(onlyNum);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looping is not a good option if we can apply linq or regex to do the job.

Comment: You're right of course, however the question was about chars and ints (specifically detecting if a char is a digit) so I answered in the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 3):

```
int iNum = 2;

char cChar = iNum.ToString()[0];
```

Will work for x when 0 <= x <= 9.

Comment: char is a singleton value anyway, we cannot convert 2 digits to a single char unless we are dealing with ASCII code. :p

Answer (score 3):

You can just cast an `int` to a `char` it directly:

```
var myChar = (char)20;
```

But to do what you want I suggest using a regular expression:

```
var onlyNumerals = Regex.Replace(myString, @"[^0-9]", "");
```

The above will replace any character that is not 0-9 with an empty space.

An alternative, using LINQ and `char.IsDigit`:

```
 var onlyNumeral = new string(myString.Where(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

Comment: Oh did not know 2nd one. Thanks for that

Comment: Casting to `char` will give you the ASCII character. For example, `(char)20` returns [DC4 (Device Control 4)](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-control-characters/device-control-four-4-ascii-code-20.html). The goal of OP is to convert `'5'` to `5`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it as:

```
string justNumbers = new String(text.Where(Char.IsDigit).ToArray());
```

Comment: `... text.Where(c=>Char.IsDigit(c)) ...` ;-)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't just post a single line of code. Explain it. -1

Comment: @Manishearth You can use comments for suggestion, but down Vote is not the option, read above down vote FAQ first. http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down

Comment: `Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended post,`Make sense? Also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/130046/when-should-i-vote

Comment: @Manishearth you think this is sloppy? or no effort :)

Comment: @Manishearth go ahead and put down votes for other answers without no comments.

Comment: No effort. I know that there are lots of such code-only answers on SO, but that's no reason to do the same. Explain your posts and make them substantiative. Otherwise its liable to deletion/downvotes.

Answer (score -2):

A few ways:

```
(char)int
```

Or

```
int.Parse(char.ToString())
```

Or

```
Convert.ToChar(int);
```

Comment: I've already tried 2 of them. They don't work. 2nd one I did not try and i cannot use it on boolean.

Comment: Casting to `char` will give you the ASCII character. The goal of OP is to convert `'5'` to `5`.